# Why are specific asserts better than generic asserts, in PHPUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, phpunit

Please excuse my ignorance; I am still new to the unit testing realm.

Can someone explain why..

`$this->assertGreaterThan( 2, $result );`

..is better than..

`$this->assertTrue( $result > 2 );`

..(and likewise, all the other specific assert methods)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you showed your mum/dad/uncle those, the `assertGreaterThan` is far more intuitive. Plus the failed message for the isGreaterThan will be much better

```
"1 was not greater than 2"
```

or

```
"false was not true"
```

Which one is more *expressive*?

Comment: Thank you Martin. Also, I should add what a friend of mine mentioned: "The libraries are extensible, so if for some reason you wanted all GreaterThan checks to do something special, it would just be a matter of extending and defining your own routine."

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the *best* method provides better readability *and* better failure messages: use the [PHPUnit function-based assertions](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/PHPUnit/Framework/Assert/Functions.php) or [Hamcrest library](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/TutorialPHP).

```
assertThat(count($users), greaterThan(2));

>> Expected: greater than 2
>>      but: was 1
```

or

```
assertThat($users, arrayWithSize(greaterThan(2)));

>> Expected: array with size greater than 2
>>      but: was array with size 1
```

You can always provide a readable error message with any assertion by adding a string as the first parameter to the assertion methods or Hamcrest's `assertThat` function or the third parameter to PHPUnit's `assertThat` function:

```
self::assertTrue('At least one user found', !empty($users));

>> At least one user found
>> Expected: true
>>      but: false
```

or

```
assertThat('At least one user found', !empty($users), is(true));

>> At least one user found
>> Expected: true
>>      but: false
```

Comment: Hamcrest looks quite nice. I'm definitely going to give this a serious look. In your experience, does Hamcrest impact PHPUnit extension? Thanks

Comment: @Spot - We've been using them together for over two years with no issues. To have PHPUnit count the number of assertions performed, you'll need to use a [custom test case](https://gist.github.com/3965902) that overrides `runBare`. If you already have your own abstract test case as we did, it's trivial to add this in.

Answer (score 0):

> is better than ...

Who says so? Both are just as good. Readability is different in both cases, but neither is particularly great. You can improve it further with some variables extraction:

```
$minimumValue = 2;
$this->assertGreaterThan($minimumValue, $result);
```

And

```
$resultGreaterThanMinimumValue = $result > 2;
$this->assertTrue($resultGreaterThanMinimumValue);
```

This is still not ideal (since those asserts don't read like a sentence in English), but neither of those two approaches is better.